# Calabash - App did not start (RuntimeError)

Tags: calabash-android

I have a error where runnig firt scenario for any feature on calabash-android .

```
Examples: Terms for search
  | term  | result |
  App did not start (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:7:in `Before'
  | carro | carro  |
  | moto  | moto   |
```

Comment: is that apk has Internet permission ?

Comment: yes. I solved waiting App is running. tks